# Search results not showing right data in DetailViewController (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, master-detail

I have 3 objects being sent to the DetailViewController (Title, Date, Body) through the default Segue func in Swift. I am only searching the Title data though. That part works perfectly but when tapping on the cell in the SearchController, it brings me to the wrong view. (Title is right in the view but the date and body don't match).

Segue func:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            var object = tableTitle[indexPath.row] as String
            var objectTwo = detailDate[indexPath.row] as String
            var objectThree = tableBody[indexPath.row] as String

            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

            if resultSearchController.isActive {

                object = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

            } else {

                object = tableTitle[indexPath.row]
                objectTwo = detailDate[indexPath.row]
                objectThree = tableBody[indexPath.row]

            }

            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.detailItemTwo = objectTwo
            controller.detailItemThree = objectThree
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

cellForRowAt func:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    let imageView = UIImage(named: "dIndicator")
    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: imageView)

    let object = tableTitle[indexPath.row]
    let objectTwo = tableBody[indexPath.row]
    let objectThree = tableDate[indexPath.row]

    if self.resultSearchController.isActive {
        cell.titleLabel!.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailLabel!.text = ""
        cell.dateLabel!.text = ""

    } else {
        cell.titleLabel!.text = object
        cell.detailLabel!.text = objectTwo
        cell.dateLabel!.text = objectThree
    }

    return cell
}
```

updateSearchResults func:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (tableTitle as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

```
struct objectsToPass {

var annTitle = [String]()
var annBody = [String]()
var annDate = [Date]()
var annDateALT = [Date]()

var tableData : [([String], [String], [Date], [Date])] {
    get {
        return [(annTitle, annBody, annDate, annDateALT)]
    }
}

}
```

Comment: look at how you're creating the objects in prepareForSegue...if the search controller is active, object = filteredTableData[indexPath.row], but objectTwo and objectThree are the same whether or not it is active.

Comment: @user3353890 how would I be able to fix this? I don't know what I should assign objectTwo and objectThree to while the searchBar is active

Comment: I would create a struct or class definition of your object with three variables: title, date, and body. Then I would have two arrays, one to store tableData, and one to store filteredTableData. Each array will contain objects of the struct or class type that you created. If search controller is active display objects from the filteredTableData array, if not, show objects from tableData array. Then when you move to detail controller, you can access the information you need by calling object.title, object.date, and object.body.

Comment: @user3353890 Alright, I'm starting off like this, am I at least going in the right direction? (Updated post)

Comment: why do you have so many arrays? I'm posting an answer below that should hopefully help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct myObject {

    var title: String
    var body: String
    var date: Date
    var altDate: Date
}
```

then have two arrays for your table data and filtered table data

```
var tableData = [myObject]()
var filteredData = [myObject]()
```